# PostgreSQL return result set as single for each tuple

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table in the below format.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat | cat2 | cat3 | cat4 |

I need this table to be transformed into a json, like the one that follows up.

```
{
    {
        "name":"A",     
        "value":"cat",  
        "type" : "String" // need to concat the "type" : "String" to every object
    },
    {
        "name":"B",
        "type":"cat2", 
        "type" : "String"
    },
    {
        "name":"C",
        "type":"cat3", 
        "type" : "String"
    },
    {
        "name":"D",
        "type":"cat4",
        "type" : "String" 
    }
}
```

All the keys are constants and values are dynamic.

Is there any postgres json function/query to obtain this output?

Comment: Your expected json is likely to have key issues, make sure it's fully correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform rows into columns first and give the required headers. Then you can use `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT` to build your json records, `JSON_AGG` to transform your set of json into a single json.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS "name", A AS "value", 'String' AS "type" FROM tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B'          , B           , 'String'           FROM tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C'          , C           , 'String'           FROM tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D'          , D           , 'String'           FROM tab
)
SELECT JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('name' , "name" , 
                                  'value', "value",
                                  'type' , "type"  )) FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b9omMXoxP5aD2tjVm59y8S/0).

---

If your "*String*" type is always the same for every row, you can also simplify the subquery and use a `CROSS JOIN` as follows.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS "name", A AS "value" FROM tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B'          , B            FROM tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C'          , C            FROM tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D'          , D            FROM tab
)
SELECT JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('name' , "name" , 
                                  'value', "value",
                                  'type' , "type"  )) FROM cte
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'String' AS "type") stringtype
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b9omMXoxP5aD2tjVm59y8S/1).